How to dynamically assign index to SwiperSlide component (react js)
{product?.skus.map((item) => (
  <SwiperSlide key={item.thumbnail.id}>
    <img className='rounded-lg' src={item.thumbnail.image} />
  </SwiperSlide>
))}

The code above renders the product images. I want to assign an ID to it so that the image can be displayed with the code below.
swiperRef.current.swiper.slideToLoop(selectedProduct!.thumbnail.id)

I used the virtualIndex property but it didn't work.
{product?.skus.map((item) => (
  <SwiperSlide key={item.thumbnail.id} virtualIndex={item.thumbnail.id}>
    <img className='rounded-lg' src={item.thumbnail.image} />
  </SwiperSlide>
))}

